# Multiple Devise Models or Single User Model

Tags: devise, cancan, roles, sti

I have a rails 4.1 application setup with **Devise**.

I have:
 one **USER** model and one **PROFILE** model. The `user has_one profile`

However, I have two types of users - Buyers and Sellers (it's a service platform and I have to use states to check if the user & profile is 100% completed to mark a user active).

Everything is working up to this level, but I am looking for some suggestion on how to model these two user types. Please note that the sellers have more responsibility, like adding portfolio items, applying for jobs etc. The buyers on other hands only post jobs and message sellers. Think of it like any other standard marketplace.

My question is:

1. Whether to use STI, please if someone can let me know how to do this, using the current setup?
2. Use roles system using Cancan or other?

The current setup is:

User model:

```
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy, autosave: true

  class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
```

All profile data of both users types is in profiles table.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Have you seen Ryan Bates' rails cast video for CanCan?

Comment: @JoeHilton Hi Joe, Thanks for your answer. Yes I have integrated roles into my app but I wanted to get some opinions on which option will work best in my case. Given my app has above setup. Do you think using cancan is the best option?

Comment: Having used CanCan previously, I'd definitely recommend using it. It's really simple to use and is extremely effective!

Comment: @JoeHilton Thanks Joe. What about the user types? Forex- I have two types of users - buyers and sellers. Now these two users have further more relationships like I explained above? How can I have separate models for both types of users, given I already have a Devise user model and associated profile model? I don't quite understand this as I am new to rails.